# What is the real use case of Python's imp.reload()?

Tags: python, dynamic, python-import, python-module, python-importlib

I'm currently reading about modules, imports and reloads, and I came across this statement in *Learning Python, 5th Edition* by Mark Lutz:

> Besides allowing you to reload (and hence rerun) modules at the
> interactive prompt, module reloads are also useful in larger systems,
> especially when the cost of restarting the entire application is
> prohibitive. For instance, game servers and systems that must connect
> to servers over a network on startup are prime candidates for dynamic
> reloads.

I know what `imp.reload()` does, but can you please give me more concrete examples of how this can be used on websites, games, or apps?

So far I've tried to manually write hard-coded values to modules, and then `imp.reload()` applied the changes, but still, how is it useful without manual mutation of source code right in IDEs?

Comment: I assume `imp` is `importlib`, correct?

Comment: Whenever you want to *reload* a module, of course.

Comment: @martineau well, `imp` was deprecated, and `importlib` does the same thing, so yeah, I meant `importlib`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga again, I understand what it does. I want to know, when would I want to reload it? What's the real project situation of doing that?

Comment: It might be useful in a debugging session after making some changes to the code in a module that you want to re-import. I've never needed it for regular code which typically doesn't change during execution.

Comment: @martineau but if I make changes to a module, it's not gonna apply without reloading. Does it mean that I need to have `imp.reload()` after every single statement in code I'm debugging? Otherwise how is it gonna aply?

Comment: You have have to reload the module to test any changes made it, whether they were to one line or many.